# Retrofit Soap response simpleframework Element 'Body' does not have

Tags: android, soap, retrofit, simple-framework

I am using retrofit for soap service and I get Element 'Body' does not have .. error. I am not good with soap :)
Here my response and my objects

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <EncryptResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <EncryptResult>%%UmVxdWVzdElzVmFsaWQyOTowMToyMDE1IDE2OjMx%%</EncryptResult>
    </EncryptResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

EncryptResponseEnvelope

```
@Root(name = "soap:Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace( prefix = "xsi", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        @Namespace( prefix = "xsd", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
        @Namespace( prefix = "soap", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
})
public class EncryptResponseEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "soap:Body", required = false)
    private EncryptResponseBody body;

    public EncryptResponseBody getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(EncryptResponseBody body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

EncryptResponseBody

```
@Root(name = "soap:Body", strict = false)
public class EncryptResponseBody {

    @Element(name = "EncryptResponse", required = false)
    private EncryptResponseData encryptResponseData;


    public EncryptResponseData getEncryptResponseData() {
        return encryptResponseData;
    }

    public void setEncryptResponseData(EncryptResponseData encryptResponseData) {
        this.encryptResponseData = encryptResponseData;
    }
}
```

EncryptResponseData

```
@Root(name = "EncryptResponse", strict = false)
@Namespace(reference = "http://tempuri.org/")
public class EncryptResponseData {

    @Element(name = "EncryptResult", required = false)
    private String encryptResult;

    public String getEncryptResult() {
        return encryptResult;
    }

    public void setEncryptResult(String encryptResult) {
        this.encryptResult = encryptResult;
    }
}
```

and it is my error :

> org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Body' does not
>   have a match in class
>   com.package.chal.data.response.encrypt_response.EncryptResponseEnvelope
>   at line 1

where do i make mistakes?

Answer (score 2):

SOAP Envelope :

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace;
import org.simpleframework.xml.NamespaceList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="soap:Envelope", strict=false)
@NamespaceList({
    @Namespace(reference="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", prefix="soap"),
    @Namespace(reference="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", prefix="xsd"),
    @Namespace(reference="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", prefix="xsi")
})
public class Envelope {

    @Element(name="Body")
    private Body body;

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

SOAP Body :

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementUnion;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Path;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(strict = false)
@Namespace(reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", prefix = "soap")
public class Body {
    // By using ElementUnion, you can re-use the Envelope/Body classes for
    // a variety of messages...
    @ElementUnion({
        // @Element(name="login", type=Login.class),
        @Element(name = "EncryptResponse", type = EncryptResponse.class) })
    public Object payload;
}
```

SOAP payload :

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
@Namespace(reference="http://tempuri.org/")
public class EncryptResponse {
    @Element
    public String EncryptResult;
}
```

I tested this solution and it works for both serialize/deserialize.

Comment: I have added this and working fine, while I am geting the response body is null, Any suggetion for this ?? 

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
  if (response != null){
    Log.i(TAG, "response: "+response.toString());
    Response res = response.body();
In this body is null for me

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and according to Chris's answer 
I only changed my body class element name like;

from

```
@Element(name = "soap:Body", required = false)
```

to

```
@Element(name="Body")
```

then it works fine right now.